# How to notify observers after filtering LiveData<List<Note>> using SearchView in ViewModel?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

I have an entity named `Note`, along with its data access object (`NoteDAO`) that contains SQL-specific logic. There's also a `NoteDatabase` class that extends `RoomDatabase` and a `NoteRepository` that utilizes both `NoteDAO` and `NoteDatabase`. The `NoteViewModel` interacts with the database through NoteRepository.

In a fragment, I use `NoteViewModel` to retrieve all notes in the `onCreateView`. After observing these notes, I set the `RecyclerView` items using `adapter.submitList`.

However, when incorporating a `SearchView`, I face an issue. While I can retrieve the query text from `SearchView`, my attempt to filter the underlying `allNotes` (a member variable in NoteViewModel of type `LiveData<List<Note>>`) didn't notify the observers as expected.

On learning about the distinction between `MutableLiveData` and `LiveData`, I considered changing the `allNotes` member in `NoteViewModel` to `MutableLiveData`. This should theoretically allow me to use the `setValue` or `postValue` methods inside the `filterNotes(String searchTerm)` function, hence notifying the observers. But this didn't work – I couldn't retrieve even the unfiltered notes list with `MutableLiveData`.

FirstFragment

```java
@Override
public View onCreateView(
        .......
) {
    ........

    RecyclerView recyclerView = binding.recyclerView;
    final NoteListAdapter adapter = new NoteListAdapter(new NoteListAdapter.WordDiff());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    mNoteViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(NoteViewModel.class);

    mNoteViewModel.getAllNotes().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<Note>>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(List<Note> notes) {
                    Log.d("MainPage", "onChanged: " + notes);
                    adapter.submitList(notes);
                }
            });
   
    ........
}
```

NoteViewModel

```java
public class NoteViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private final NoteRepository mRepository;

    private final LiveData<List<Note>> mAllNotes;

    public NoteViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        mRepository = new NoteRepository(application);
        mAllNotes = mRepository.getAllNotes();
    }

    LiveData<List<Note>> getAllNotes() {
        return mAllNotes;
    }

    public void insert (Note note) { mRepository.insert(note); }
}
```

NoteRepository

```java
public class NoteRepository {

    private final NoteDAO mNoteDAO;

    @NotNull
    private final LiveData<List<Note>> mAllNotes;

    NoteRepository(Application application) {
        NoteRoomDatabase db = NoteRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application);
        mNoteDAO = db.noteDAO();
        mAllNotes = mNoteDAO.getAllNotes();
    }

    public LiveData<List<Note>> getAllNotes() {
        return mAllNotes;
    }

    public void insert(Note note) {
        NoteRoomDatabase.databaseWriteExecutor.execute(() -> {
            mNoteDAO.insert(note);
        });
    }

}
```

NoteDAO

```java
@Dao
public interface NoteDAO {

    @Insert
    void insert(Note note);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM notes ORDER BY id DESC")
    LiveData<List<Note>> getAllNotes();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM notes where title = :title ORDER BY id DESC")
    LiveData<List<Note>> getNotesByTitle(String title);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM notes where id = :id ORDER BY id DESC")
    LiveData<Note> getNoteById(long id);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM notes where color = :color ORDER BY id DESC")
    LiveData<List<Note>> getNotesByColor(String color);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have two approach

1. Please make use of **Kotlin flow** instead of livedata. You can use powerful flow extension function which will fulfill your needs. Here is an example

```
class NoteViewModel():AndroidViewModel{
 private val noteItemsFlow = combine(mAllNotes, searchQueryFlow){ items, query ->
        items.filter{
            it.noteName.contains(query) // Here you can write a logic to filter according to search query
        }
    }
}

// In Fragment
noteItemsFlow.collectLatest{
   adapter.submitList(it)
}
```

2. You can implement or extend filterable class in Recycler adapter and override getFilter method here is the code

```
class NoteListAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(), Filterable {
    val notes = ArrayList<Note>()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return NoteVieHolder()
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return notes.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        // Replace your onBindViewHolder code here
    }

    inner class NoteVieHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder(){
        // Replace your view holder code here
    }


    fun submitList(latestNotes:List<Note>){
        notes.clear()
        notes.addAll(latestNotes)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun getFilter(): Filter {
        return  object : Filter() {
            override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): FilterResults {
                val results = FilterResults()
                if (!constraint.isNullOrEmpty()){
                    val filterNotes = notes.filter { 
                        it.title.contains(constraint)
                    }
                    results.count = filterNotes.size
                    results.values = filterNotes
                }else{
                    results.count = notes.size
                    results.values = notes
                }
                
                return  results
            }

            override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: FilterResults?) {
                if (results?.values != null) {
                    submitList(results.values as List<Note>)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps